# Dynamic list of buttons in Unity UI Scrollview not showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas which contains a panel housing a scroll view. (The scroll view contains the default Viewport -> Content setup). I don't think it's relavent but I removed the scroll bars.

I want to display a dynamic list of prefabs (buttons) in the scroll view. When debugging, I can see that the prefabs are being created correctly with the Content as the parent, but nothing shows up in the scrollview.

I followed a tutorial that had me add Vertical Layout Group and Content Size Fitter components to the Content GameObject. I tried to play around with the options in those components while running to see if I had them misconfigured, but the prefabs were never displayed.

Before running:

[image: Structure]

[image: Content GameObject]

After running:

[image: After running test code]

Shouldn't really matter much but here's the code I am using for testing. (In `Start()` - and I know this isn't the most efficient.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      Game game = new Game
      {
        ID = i.ToString(),
        OpponentID = i.ToString(),
        OpponentImage = "pig",
        OpponentName = "Test " + i,
        OpponentScore = new Score { Pigs = 2, Bulls = 1 },
        Points = 350,
        Score = new Score { Pigs = 1, Bulls = 1 },
        Status = "active",
        Turn = "6XMvi7Xv2maXDdFN7dwrhLaMrkE3"
      };

      var gameObj = Instantiate(gamePrefab, scrollViewContent.transform, false);
      var canvas = gameObj.transform.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
      canvas.enabled = false;

      var gameObjButton = canvas.transform.GetChild(0);

      gameObjButton.Find("OpponentInfo").Find("OpponentName").GetComponent<Text>().text = game.OpponentName;
      gameObjButton.Find("OpponentInfo").Find("OpponentScore").GetComponent<Text>().text = game.OpponentScore.ToString();
      // //   gameObj.transform.Find("OpponentProfilePicture").GetComponent<Image>()

      gameObjButton.Find("OpponentInfo").Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().text = GameObject.Find("FirebaseRef")?.GetComponent<FirebaseRef>()?.user?.UserId;
      
      gameObjButton.Find("PlayerInfo").Find("PlayerScore").GetComponent<Text>().text = game.Score.ToString();
      gameObjButton.Find("PlayerInfo").Find("PlayerPoints").GetComponent<Text>().text = game.Points.ToString();

      canvas.enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: a) you don't want to stretch the `Content` to the same size as the `Viewport`! Then what the scroll for? You want to scale it so that all child content fit into it! b) I think you would also want `use child size` enabled for the `height` so your elements don't overlap vertically

Comment: And yes indeed instead of all these `Find` rather have a toplevel component on your prefab that already knows all these references and where you can initialize the content with a single method call ... Oh also: you shouldn't nest the Canvas .. there already is a canvas for your scroll view so your individual buttons don't need to / Shouldn't have one!